# First and last element ruby has [" and "]

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get a array from a string passed as parameters to match a dictionary after.

My code:

```
def substrings(*args, dictionary)
  words = args.to_s.split(" ")

  puts words[0]
  puts words[1]
  puts words[2]

end


substrings("below as above", dictionary)
```

The result is

```
["below
as
above"]
```

Why the first and last elements has this [" and "]??

Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 6):

`*` in `*args` means that you collect arbitrary amount of arguments in array `args`, so `"below as above"` transforms into `["below as above"]` array, and `.to_s` converts it into string `'["below as above]'`, that's why you receive this strange result.

If you want only one (first) string argument, you may change code as below:

```
def substrings(str, dictionary)
  words = str.split

  puts words[0]
  puts words[1]
  puts words[2]

end


substrings("below as above", dictionary)
# output:
# below
# as
# above
```

Or, if you really want to pass any amount of strings:

```
def substrings(*args, dictionary)
  words = args.map(&:split).flatten

  words.each { |word| puts word }
end


substrings("below as above", "foo is not a bar", dictionary)
# output:
# below
# as
# above
# foo
# is
# not
# a
# bar
```

Comment: Got it, and I appreciated the attention.

Comment: Don't forget `flat_map` instead of `map(...).flatten`.